# Unable to get data from server and even browser is not opening any url but Internet is connected

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-asynctask, android-memory, android-background

In my android device internet is connected and it's showing the connected status. But i am running my application then it's not working. Even internet is not running in browser.

I have just uninstall my application and then try to run the internet in device but same issue. below is my log please check it.

**My complete log** :[My Complete Log](http://pastebin.com/zPmfSyHf)

**--------- beginning of /dev/log/system**

```
11-07 05:57:27.281 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings } from pid 212
        11-07 05:57:39.481 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.AdvancedSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:58:04.291 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:58:10.891 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.StorageUse } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:58:16.351 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.DevelopmentSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:58:27.491 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.EthernetSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:58:27.541 I/EthernetManager(19530): Init Ethernet Manager, service: android.net.ethernet.IEthernetManager$Stub$Proxy@40597e50
        11-07 05:58:27.581 V/EthernetService(129): device 0 name eth0
        11-07 05:58:27.581 V/EtherenetSettings(19530): found device: eth0
        11-07 05:58:37.591 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.DeviceInfoSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:58:57.391 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings } from pid 212
        11-07 05:59:04.441 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.SecuritySettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:59:11.941 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.DeviceAdminSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:59:21.151 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.VoiceInputOutputSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 05:59:57.061 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.nolanlawson.logcat/.LogcatActivity } from pid 212
        11-07 06:01:14.691 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): report new state DISCONNECTED on dev eth0
        11-07 06:01:14.691 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): update network state tracker
        11-07 06:01:14.691 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received disconnected events, stack=true HW=true
        11-07 06:01:14.691 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): stop dhcp and interface, suspend:true
        11-07 06:01:14.691 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): stop DHCP eth0
        11-07 06:01:15.691 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): reset Static IP of eth0
        11-07 06:01:15.711 D/StatusBarPolicy(243): updateEth(): Event: Interface NG
        11-07 06:05:28.411 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.openintents.filemanager/.FileManagerActivity } from pid 212
        11-07 06:06:06.581 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/catlog/saved_logs/2013-11-07-06-05-17.txt typ=text/plain cmp=com.android.htmlviewer/.HTMLViewerActivity } from pid 8835
        11-07 06:06:06.621 I/ActivityManager(129): Start proc com.android.htmlviewer for activity com.android.htmlviewer/.HTMLViewerActivity: pid=21252 uid=10029 gids={}
        11-07 06:06:09.561 W/InputManagerService(129): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406a3840 (uid=10029 pid=21252)
        11-07 06:06:10.111 W/InputManagerService(129): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406a3840 (uid=10029 pid=21252)
        11-07 06:06:15.891 D/DirectVolume(52): Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard partition 179:9 removed
        11-07 06:06:15.891 D/Vold    (52): Volume sdcard state changing 4 (Mounted) -> 5 (Unmounting)
        11-07 06:06:15.891 I/MountService(129): onEvent:: raw= 632 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard bad removal (179:9) cooked =  632 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard bad removal (179:9)
        11-07 06:06:15.891 I/MountService(129): Sending unmounted event first
        11-07 06:06:15.891 D/MountService(129): volume state changed for /mnt/sdcard (mounted -> unmounted)
        11-07 06:06:15.891 I/StorageNotification(243): Media {/mnt/sdcard} state changed from {mounted} -> {unmounted}
        11-07 06:06:15.891 D/VoldCmdListener(52): volume shared /mnt/sdcard ums
        11-07 06:06:15.891 I/MountService(129): Sending media bad removal
        11-07 06:06:15.891 D/MountService(129): volume state changed for /mnt/sdcard (unmounted -> bad_removal)
        11-07 06:06:15.891 I/MountService(129): onEvent:: raw= 605 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard state changed from 4 (Mounted) to 5 (Unmounting) cooked =  605 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard state changed from 4 (Mounted) to 5 (Unmounting)
        11-07 06:06:15.891 I/MountService(129): notifyVolumeStateChanged::bad_removal
        11-07 06:06:15.901 I/StorageNotification(243): Media {/mnt/sdcard} state changed from {unmounted} -> {bad_removal}
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/Vold    (52): /mnt/secure/staging/.android_secure sucessfully unmounted
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/Vold    (52): /mnt/secure/asec sucessfully unmounted
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/Vold    (52): /mnt/secure/staging sucessfully unmounted
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/Vold    (52): /mnt/sdcard unmounted sucessfully
        11-07 06:06:18.281 D/Vold    (52): Volume sdcard state changing 5 (Unmounting) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
        11-07 06:06:18.281 D/DirectVolume(52): Crisis averted
        11-07 06:06:18.281 D/DirectVolume(52): Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard disk 179:8 removed
        11-07 06:06:18.281 D/Vold    (52): Volume sdcard state changing 1 (Idle-Unmounted) -> 0 (No-Media)
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/MountService(129): onEvent:: raw= 605 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard state changed from 5 (Unmounting) to 1 (Idle-Unmounted) cooked =  605 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard state changed from 5 (Unmounting) to 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/MountService(129): notifyVolumeStateChanged::bad_removal
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/MountService(129): onEvent:: raw= 631 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard disk removed (179:8) cooked =  631 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard disk removed (179:8)
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/MountService(129): onEvent:: raw= 605 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard state changed from 1 (Idle-Unmounted) to 0 (No-Media) cooked =  605 Volume sdcard /mnt/sdcard state changed from 1 (Idle-Unmounted) to 0 (No-Media)
        11-07 06:06:18.281 I/MountService(129): notifyVolumeStateChanged::bad_removal
        11-07 06:06:20.111 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher } from pid 129
        11-07 06:06:20.191 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want com.lineprinter (pid 20358): hidden #16
        11-07 06:07:59.991 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want com.testingposfeatures (pid 20575): hidden #16
        11-07 06:17:59.991 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want jp.co.casio.caios.app.standardregister841 (pid 20649): hidden #16
        11-07 06:18:00.001 W/ActivityManager(129): Scheduling restart of crashed service jp.co.casio.caios.app.standardregister841/jp.co.casio.caios.component.register.sales.logic.check.CheckMaster in 5000ms
        11-07 06:18:05.011 I/ActivityManager(129): Start proc jp.co.casio.caios.app.standardregister841 for service jp.co.casio.caios.app.standardregister841/jp.co.casio.caios.component.register.sales.logic.check.CheckMaster: pid=21281 uid=10031 gids={1015, 3003}
        11-07 06:23:59.991 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want jp.co.casio.caios.app.generalcontrol:service (pid 20757): hidden #16
        11-07 06:24:00.001 W/ActivityManager(129): Scheduling restart of crashed service jp.co.casio.caios.app.generalcontrol/.NetworkService in 5000ms
        11-07 06:24:05.021 I/ActivityManager(129): Start proc jp.co.casio.caios.app.generalcontrol:service for service jp.co.casio.caios.app.generalcontrol/.NetworkService: pid=21294 uid=10031 gids={1015, 3003}
        11-07 06:24:59.991 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want jp.co.casio.caios.app.shared (pid 21010): hidden #16
        11-07 06:25:00.021 W/ActivityManager(129): Scheduling restart of crashed service jp.co.casio.caios.app.shared/jp.co.casio.caios.component.shared.logic.CustRsvService in 5000ms
        11-07 06:25:05.021 I/ActivityManager(129): Start proc jp.co.casio.caios.app.shared for service jp.co.casio.caios.app.shared/jp.co.casio.caios.component.shared.logic.CustRsvService: pid=21307 uid=10031 gids={1015, 3003}
        11-07 06:36:44.301 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings } from pid 212
        11-07 06:36:45.881 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:36:47.701 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.ManageApplications } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:37:02.011 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:jp.co.casio.caios.app.advertise cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:37:13.271 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:jp.co.casio.caios.app.applicationinstall cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:37:23.061 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.StorageUse } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:37:31.771 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:posimplicity.in cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:37:56.501 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:com.posimplicity cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:38:02.521 I/ActivityManager(129): Force stopping package com.posimplicity uid=10036
        11-07 06:38:02.591 W/InputManagerService(129): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406ca4e0
        11-07 06:38:48.561 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:39:13.141 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.ManageApplications } from pid 212
        11-07 06:39:20.151 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:com.android.wallpaper cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:39:27.361 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS dat=package:com.casio.salesmanagementapp.environmentdefinition841 cmp=com.android.settings/.applications.InstalledAppDetails } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:39:36.761 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=posimplicity.in/.Splash_Activity } from pid 212
        11-07 06:39:36.821 I/ActivityManager(129): Start proc posimplicity.in for activity posimplicity.in/.Splash_Activity: pid=21336 uid=10035 gids={3003}
        11-07 06:39:38.921 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { cmp=posimplicity.in/.Splash_Activity } from pid 21336
        11-07 06:39:38.941 W/InputManagerService(129): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4074c960 (uid=10035 pid=21336)
        11-07 06:39:38.941 W/InputManagerService(129): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40720aa8
        11-07 06:39:40.061 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { cmp=posimplicity.in/.Splash_Activity } from pid 21336
        11-07 06:39:40.081 W/InputManagerService(129): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4074c960 (uid=10035 pid=21336)
        11-07 06:39:40.081 W/InputManagerService(129): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407d3d70
        11-07 06:39:58.121 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want jp.co.casio.caios.framework.ftpdatabasetransmission.service:remote (pid 21059): hidden #16
        11-07 06:39:58.131 W/ActivityManager(129): Scheduling restart of crashed service jp.co.casio.caios.framework.ftpdatabasetransmission.service/.DatabaseTransmissionService in 5000ms
        11-07 06:40:03.141 I/ActivityManager(129): Start proc jp.co.casio.caios.framework.ftpdatabasetransmission.service:remote for service jp.co.casio.caios.framework.ftpdatabasetransmission.service/.DatabaseTransmissionService: pid=21345 uid=10031 gids={1015, 3003}
        11-07 06:40:19.661 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } from pid 212
        11-07 06:40:19.671 I/ActivityManager(129): Start proc com.android.browser for activity com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity: pid=21353 uid=10017 gids={3003, 1015}
        11-07 06:40:20.191 W/InputManagerService(129): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40881098 (uid=10017 pid=21353)
        11-07 06:40:20.191 W/InputManagerService(129): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406ece20
        11-07 06:40:32.101 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): report interface is up for eth0
        11-07 06:40:32.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): interface up event, kick off connection request
        11-07 06:40:32.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): trigger dhcp for device eth0
        11-07 06:40:32.101 D/EthernetStateTracker(129): DhcpHandler: DHCP request started
        11-07 06:40:32.201 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): report new state CONNECTED on dev eth0
        11-07 06:40:32.201 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): update network state tracker
        11-07 06:40:32.201 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received HW connected, stack=false HW=false
        11-07 06:40:32.201 D/StatusBarPolicy(243): updateEth(): Event: Interface OK
        11-07 06:40:32.241 D/ConnectivityService(129): No network info for EVENT_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED 
        11-07 06:40:34.101 D/EthernetStateTracker(129): DhcpHandler: DHCP request succeeded: ipaddr 192.168.0.82 gateway 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dns1 192.168.0.1 dns2 0.0.0.0 DHCP server 192.168.0.1 lease 43200 seconds
        11-07 06:40:34.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received configured succeeded, stack=false HW=true
        11-07 06:40:34.101 D/ConnectivityService(129): No network info for EVENT_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED 
        11-07 06:41:16.931 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:41:16.951 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] cmp=com.android.quicksearchbox/.google.GoogleSearch (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:41:17.001 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/m?hl=en&gl=us&source=android-browser-type&q=clean+android+device+using+garbage+collertor flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 8874
        11-07 06:41:17.011 W/ActivityManager(129): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{4066e240 com.android.quicksearchbox/.google.GoogleSearch}
        11-07 06:41:17.031 W/InputManagerService(129): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@406285a0
        11-07 06:41:39.391 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/ flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:41:43.281 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:41:45.931 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:41:50.151 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:41:52.591 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:44:35.551 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:44:38.621 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:45:31.201 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/ flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:45:39.971 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/m?hl=en&gl=us&source=android-browser-type&q=facebook flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:45:57.071 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.co.in/ flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:46:22.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): report new state DISCONNECTED on dev eth0
        11-07 06:46:22.141 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): update network state tracker
        11-07 06:46:22.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received disconnected events, stack=true HW=true
        11-07 06:46:22.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): stop dhcp and interface, suspend:true
        11-07 06:46:22.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): stop DHCP eth0
        11-07 06:46:23.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): reset Static IP of eth0
        11-07 06:46:23.151 D/StatusBarPolicy(243): updateEth(): Event: Interface NG
        11-07 06:54:59.991 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want com.android.packageinstaller (pid 19996): hidden #16
        11-07 06:55:21.101 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): report interface is up for eth0
        11-07 06:55:21.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): interface up event, kick off connection request
        11-07 06:55:21.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): trigger dhcp for device eth0
        11-07 06:55:21.101 D/EthernetStateTracker(129): DhcpHandler: DHCP request started
        11-07 06:55:21.201 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): report new state CONNECTED on dev eth0
        11-07 06:55:21.201 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): update network state tracker
        11-07 06:55:21.201 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received HW connected, stack=false HW=false
        11-07 06:55:21.201 D/StatusBarPolicy(243): updateEth(): Event: Interface OK
        11-07 06:55:21.201 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want com.android.defcontainer (pid 8851): hidden #16
        11-07 06:55:21.211 D/ConnectivityService(129): No network info for EVENT_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED 
        11-07 06:55:23.101 D/EthernetStateTracker(129): DhcpHandler: DHCP request succeeded: ipaddr 192.168.0.82 gateway 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dns1 192.168.0.1 dns2 0.0.0.0 DHCP server 192.168.0.1 lease 43200 seconds
        11-07 06:55:23.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received configured succeeded, stack=false HW=true
        11-07 06:55:23.101 D/ConnectivityService(129): No network info for EVENT_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED 
        11-07 06:55:24.601 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher } from pid 129
        11-07 06:55:24.691 I/ActivityManager(129): No longer want com.edwardkim.android.screenshotitfull (pid 8867): hidden #16
        11-07 06:55:31.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): report new state DISCONNECTED on dev eth0
        11-07 06:55:31.141 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): update network state tracker
        11-07 06:55:31.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received disconnected events, stack=true HW=true
        11-07 06:55:31.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): stop dhcp and interface, suspend:true
        11-07 06:55:31.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): stop DHCP eth0
        11-07 06:55:32.141 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): reset Static IP of eth0
        11-07 06:55:32.151 D/StatusBarPolicy(243): updateEth(): Event: Interface NG
        11-07 06:55:36.101 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): report interface is up for eth0
        11-07 06:55:36.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): interface up event, kick off connection request
        11-07 06:55:36.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): trigger dhcp for device eth0
        11-07 06:55:36.101 D/EthernetStateTracker(129): DhcpHandler: DHCP request started
        11-07 06:55:36.201 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): report new state CONNECTED on dev eth0
        11-07 06:55:36.201 V/EthernetStateTracker(129): update network state tracker
        11-07 06:55:36.201 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received HW connected, stack=false HW=false
        11-07 06:55:36.201 D/StatusBarPolicy(243): updateEth(): Event: Interface OK
        11-07 06:55:36.221 D/ConnectivityService(129): No network info for EVENT_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED 
        11-07 06:55:38.061 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } from pid 212
        11-07 06:55:38.101 D/EthernetStateTracker(129): DhcpHandler: DHCP request succeeded: ipaddr 192.168.0.82 gateway 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dns1 192.168.0.1 dns2 0.0.0.0 DHCP server 192.168.0.1 lease 43200 seconds
        11-07 06:55:38.101 I/EthernetStateTracker(129): received configured succeeded, stack=false HW=true
        11-07 06:55:38.101 D/ConnectivityService(129): No network info for EVENT_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED 
        11-07 06:55:41.941 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) } from pid 21353
        11-07 06:55:53.061 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher } from pid 129
        11-07 06:55:59.151 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings } from pid 212
        11-07 06:56:00.891 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.ApplicationSettings } from pid 19530
        11-07 06:56:02.061 I/ActivityManager(129): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.android.settings/.ManageApplications } from pid 19530
```

I think this is due to memory leak because i find the below line in log when try to open google in device

```
11-07 22:53:05.055 E/QSB.CursorBackedSuggestionCursor(8874): LEAK! Finalized without being closed: Source{name=com.android.quicksearchbox/.google.GoogleSearch}[facebook]
```

I have unistall the application but still getting this issue. i was getting data in that application inside AsynTask in background. 
Please guide me how to deal with this.
**My question is if the whole memory is leaked then how to free that whole memory in the device.**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The logs are full of `UnknownHostException`. You seem to have a DNS issue. Check if you can resolve domains from other machines in the same network (You can try `nslookup google.com`)

Answer (score 0):

**if the whole memory is leaked then how to free that whole memory in the device.**

First of all, separate the *Model* (in *MVC* sense, *Model-View-Controller*) from *Controller*. That is, an `Activity` is a *Controller*, it gets re-created when the device orientation changes. Do not keep any data that must survive the orientation change in the `Activity`.

Now, about clearing the leaked memory.

Put the dangerous (potentially leaking memory) code into a separate Activity or Service.

Declare that Activity or Service to run in a separate process. In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <service
        android:name=".XYZServiceA"
        android:process=":xyzServiceA"
        >
    </service>
```

Kill the process.

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

You also can do `System.exit()`, but that behaves differently in different versions of Android.

Comment: Put the dangerous code into a separate Activity or Service. why that is dangerous ?

Comment: Because it is expected to leak memory.